# What would happen if a spaceship had a total power failure in regards to the crew?

Tags: science-fiction, spaceships, atmosphere, science-in-society

On a spaceship with a total loss of power, say for instance, because of a system failure or something, what would happen to the people aboard? Would they become hypoxic? And would it get warmer or colder aboard ship?

Comment: It depends on your spaceship and its location.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, George! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods. Have fun!

Comment: Since catastrophic power loss [has actually happened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13), would those answers work?.

Comment: @user535733 Apollo 13 did not suffer a complete power loss. The event can provide some evidence for some aspects of the situation given a similar ship, but it's hardly an answer on its own.

Comment: Hi, thanks guys, yes that's a great help thank you very much 

Comment: @Samuel, I'm gonna disagree on that one.  You are correct that it didn't suffer 100% power loss, but they had to shut down the heaters.  It's close enough to what the OP's looking for that it's a better-than-average indicator of what would really happen.  (Cold... lots and lots of cold...)

Comment: @JBH And communications? They still had those. Complete power loss is a very different story.

Comment: @Samuel, communications don't keep you alive.  Just sane.  I don't believe comms alone make it a "very different story."  Other than a few lights, what life-sustaining technologies were powered?  That's a relevant question.  Heat was off, air circulation was on.  Food was frozen.  Water?  I don't know about that.  Fred Haise had a kidney infection, he quite doubtfully would have survived a full week under those conditions.

Comment: @Samuel, you know... I can imagine a short story about some [poor unfortunate soul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfkkMHieqcI) who's left without power save for a single blinking light behind a panel that he hasn't the tools to remove.  His salvation, the power he needs to survive, behind 2mm of impenetrable metal.  And he slowly starts to go mad....  Now it's a race between death and madness and the wonder of which is worse....

Comment: People are voting your question "too broad."  Please help by explaining specifically the space ship we're talking about.  Obviously a ship that houses 5,000 active troops is different from a colony ship with 100,000 hibernating people vs. Apollo 13 with just 3 people.  Telling us what we're working with (tech, people, size, etc.) should stop the close voting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends a lot on factors that I simply don't know enough about, *but* there are a few things.

- **Heat** is a significant thing. Spacecraft have a hard time getting rid of heat, but that said, there's a lot of passive heat-removal systems that don't require power. And, with a complete loss of power, a lot of your heat producers are disabled as well.
- **Carbon Dioxide** is an issue, but also maybe not. It depends on the person and the activity and the ship. In space, things just... stay where they are. Without any sort of fans or anything to move air, someone staying in the same place will 'build' a cloud of Carbon Dioxide around their head. But if they move around, it will be spread out. So, bad news for the one who's sleeping when the power is lost. The rest of the crew would have to wake/move them so they don't suffocate on their own exhalations. Moving air around is also fairly easy to do manually - Grab some folders and fan at things. Not perfect, but a significant help.

Realistically, there's a decent amount of time to do things to restore the power. How long it is depends on the ship and the crew and what the crew does and where the ship is, etc. I'm sure someone here has better knowledge of that than I do and can give you better answers.

There are also some other, more minor things to keep in mind:

- **Human Waste** is now an issue. Pretty much every spacecraft has had some sort of fancy space toilet that typically needs power to work. Using the bathroom now becomes significantly more complicated.
- **Station keeping** by the vessel is now inactive. They can't dodge any debris in orbit, nor can they maintain their orbit. Even the ISS has to use small thrusters to keep itself in the correct orbit. This is a long-term problem, for certain, but the longer it goes on, the worse it gets.
- **Food** might get annoying. A lot of the food they eat on the ISS goes through a rehydration process, which if I remember correctly uses a powered machine. You can't really just stick things in a cup of water and call it good, since water getting places you don't want it to can be Very Bad. On the other hand, the food generally doesn't have to be refrigerated (It's mostly freeze-dried), and stores pretty well, so it's just a matter of eating dry things and drinking more water than they might otherwise have to.

I'm sure that's not *all* of the effects - There's probably huge lists of minor things that go wrong when power is lost - but complete loss of power by itself isn't necessarily going to immediately kill or threaten anyone so long as people are aware and take the right measures. I'd be more worried about *why* power was lost.

Answer (score 0):

**You can make this happen in whatever way makes your story good.**

You could plausibly have the crew spaces get very cold when the heat when off.  But what if it were a fission powered space craft?  Without coolant circulating up to the radiators the fission engine might get very hot and threaten a meltdown.

You might have CO2 building up if air were not circulating past the scrubbers.  On the other hand if your CO2 were handled by banks of algae that might not be an issue.  Or the algae might not photosynthesize if they were dark.  But maybe they run off sunlight and they would be fine.

It might get dark.  But there might be emergency lights or flashlights.

O2 might not be replenished and the air might get hypoxic. But there are tanks of O2 handy.

Regardless of your scenario and how your ship is set up I suspect the crew would not just sit around and let it happen.  That is where the story comes in.  I would definitely bust out the handcrank and get Fyodor pumping that coolant so the reactor did not go critical.  I would go get some oxygen tanks and let some of that out near Fyodor; he is working that crank pretty hard.  The CO2 scrubbers also have a manual drive option which Bethany can pedal once we hook up the stationary bike.  Since Spotify is down with our internet connection, I can keep morale high with my ukulele stylings.